# Why is it so complicated to get the ActionName in ApiController? Easier way?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-web-api

An MVC controller getting the action name and controller name:

```
public class AuthorizeController : Controller
{

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        string controllerNamespace = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.FullName;
        //..more code
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward.

But when I have an ApiController (`System.Web.Http.ApiController`), things are more complicated:

[image]

Eventually with the help of some rsharper tips I was able to reduce it to a 'few' lines.

```
private string GetActionName(HttpControllerContext context)
{
    var httpRouteDataCollection = context.RouteData.Values.Values;
    var httpRouteDataCollection2 = httpRouteDataCollection.FirstOrDefault();
    if (!(httpRouteDataCollection2 is IHttpRouteData[] httpRouteData))
    {
        return null;
    }

    IHttpRouteData routeData = httpRouteData.FirstOrDefault();
    var httpActionDescriptorCollection = routeData?.Route.DataTokens["actions"];
    if (!(httpActionDescriptorCollection is HttpActionDescriptor[] httpActionDescriptor))
    {
        return null;
    }
    HttpActionDescriptor reflectedHttpActionDescriptor = httpActionDescriptor.FirstOrDefault();
    return reflectedHttpActionDescriptor?.ActionName;
}
```

Can't it be done easier? 
Reason for asking this is because currently I am implementing a generic way of determining who can open what action. Some actions are within an WebApi and every time I would need to perform above 'querying'. So this whole conversion things eat up some performance time.

**The WHY?**

Without going in to much detail, let just assume you have 40 MVC controllers and 20 API controllers with each about 5-10 actions. All of them are stored in the database (loop through them on startup) and can be linked to an Identity role. An admin is able to choose the actions a certain role can perform. After receiving the first answers I might not be clear enough why I would like to create an controller override where I want to do the programming only once.

Comment: Pay attention that your solution won't work in case that you have several actions with the same route but with different http method

Answer (score 3):

One of the potential solutions might be an ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class ValidateAccessAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var actionName = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        ......
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

And then on your controllers:

```
    [ValidateAccess]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Stuff()
```

You can even pass arguments to those attributes and have them "smart", like for each action will belong to a certain group and validation of access will be based on a group rather action name. Which can be hard to maintain.

Eg

```
public class ValidateAccessAttribute2 : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly FunctionalArea _area;

    public ValidateAccessAttribute2(FunctionalArea area)
    {
        _area = area;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        if (!actionContext.Request.Headers.Contains(AuthorizationHeaders.UserNameHeader))
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }
        var userName = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("UserNameHeader").First();
        if (!UserCanAccessArea(userName, _area))
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }
    }
}


    [ValidateAccess2(FunctionalArea.AccessToGenericStuff)]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Stuff()
```

Comment: The grouping is actually already solved for me, I do that based on the controller (which is a section) and all the actions are...the actions for better maintainability. Eventually they are shown in a list where the user can choose what actions are allowed for who. But your solution for attribute item is valid answer although I prefer an controller solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't You use ActionContext and ControllerContext?

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var actionName = this.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        var controlerName = this.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        return this.Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I am not going to put all the authorization checking logic in EVERY action.

Comment: Good reason. 
IMHO You should use different authorization. Your approach seams kinda complecated.

Comment: Can be argued, share your thoughts, this is what I do:As far as I have seen from experience this is the most flexible way of defining what a user *can* do. Giving every action a friendly name so that an admin can define which IdentityRole can do what actions, grouping them by Sections (which are the Controllers). Besides that some system roles to create a little hierarchy for roles, eventually every activity is a POST or GET request (also API calls). Besides that a generic filter within a generic base repository for department data filtering (so department NL can only see NL customers).

Comment: And then on the front-end override the ActionLink's to disable or hide buttons. At last create if code blocks to show or hide something or change very specific things based on roles. Of course I cannot really type out here everything but I hope you get the idea! IdentityRole is eventually linked to the actions. So it also works well with the default MVC role mechanism, just overriding here and there.

Comment: Bit of both, eventually what a user can do is stored in DB but cached on web application startup. The checking of what a user can and cannot do is what is happening within the controller. But I think we are kind of going out of scope for this question though haha

Comment: It's not out os scope ;) If You use [Authorize(Roles = "{RoleName}")] in code, than You don't need to make custome validation. And admins job is only to set proper role for users. It will be much easier than Your solution (but You have to set roles in code, so its less flexible). So You have to answer one question: "Do I need to have more flexibility with cost in performance and more code"

Comment: Ah well you are hitting at that... the answer is yes. That is what we had before which was not working as desired. Having users in other countries as manager might have different thoughts on what a certain user is allowed and not allowed to do. Internally this has already lead to everyone being Admin.